# get data from database using ajax and into javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm not getting any data from the database to javascript but I get data to PHP

I use Ajax to get data from the database and get data from the PHP file to javascript and I want to filter the data using javascript so I fetch data using javascript to display the products I'm not getting data to javascript but get data to PHP file.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'user.php',
    type: 'GET',
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
    }
});


function ajax() {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.open('GET', 'user.php', true);
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onload = () => {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            let products = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log(products);
        }
    }
}

const section = document.querySelector('.cards');
const btnContainer = document.querySelector('.top ul');


window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    displayProductItems(products);
    displayMenuButtons();

});
function displayProductItems(productItems) {
    let displayProducts = productItems.map((item) => {
        return `<div class="card">
            <img src="${item.image}" alt="">
            <h3>${item.title}</h3>
            <div class="bottom">
              <span class="text-accent-2">${item.category}</span>
              <span class="price">$${item.price}</span>
            </div>
          </div>`;
    });
    displayProducts = displayProducts.join("");
    section.innerHTML = displayProducts;
}

function displayMenuButtons() {
    const sub_categories = products.reduce((values, item) => {
        if (!values.includes(item.sub_category)) {
            values.push(item.sub_category);
        }
        return values;
    }, ['all']);

    const buttons = sub_categories.map((sub_cat) => {
        return `<li><button class="filter-btn" data-id="${sub_cat}">${sub_cat}</button></li>`
    }).join("");

    btnContainer.innerHTML = buttons;
    const filterBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.filter-btn');
    filterBtn.forEach((btn) => {
        btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            const sub_cat = e.currentTarget.dataset.id;
            const productsSubCat = products.filter((productItem) => {
                if (productItem.sub_category === sub_cat) {
                    return productItem;
                };
            });
            if (sub_cat === 'all') {
                displayProductItems(products);
            } else {
                displayProductItems(productsSubCat);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Why first two functions? Which do you want to use? They seem to try fetching the same data, however you are never using the response

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

```js
let products = [];

$.ajax({
    url: 'user.php',
    type: 'GET',
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        products = JSON.parse(data);
        displayProductItems(products);
        displayMenuButtons();
    }
});

function ajax() {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'user.php', true);
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            let products = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(products);
        }
    }
}

const section = document.querySelector('.cards');
const btnContainer = document.querySelector('.top ul');

function displayProductItems(productItems) {
    let displayProducts = productItems.map((item) => {
        return `<div class="card">
            <img src="${item.image}" alt="">
            <h3>${item.title}</h3>
            <div class="bottom">
              <span class="text-accent-2">${item.category}</span>
              <span class="price">$${item.price}</span>
            </div>
          </div>`;
    }).join("");
    section.innerHTML = displayProducts;
}

function displayMenuButtons() {
    const sub_categories = products.reduce((values, item) => {
        if (!values.includes(item.sub_category)) {
            values.push(item.sub_category);
        }
        return values;
    }, ['all']);

    const buttons = sub_categories.map((sub_cat) => {
        return `<li><button class="filter-btn" data-id="${sub_cat}">${sub_cat}</button></li>`
    }).join("");

    btnContainer.innerHTML = buttons;
    const filterBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.filter-btn');
    filterBtn.forEach((btn) => {
        btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            const sub_cat = e.currentTarget.dataset.id;
            const productsSubCat = products.filter((productItem) => productItem.sub_category === sub_cat);
            if (sub_cat === 'all') {
                displayProductItems(products);
            } else {
                displayProductItems(productsSubCat);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I hope it works!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).